# Switching branch for a subdirectory only in Git

Tags: git, git-svn, git-branch

I'm working on a Git repository with two main branches and two main folders. One of these folders is very similar between the two branches, the other is very different. This means that, even if I'm just working on the common folder, switching between the two branches is slow due to all the updates required to the other folder.

Is it possible to switch the branch of a subfolder in a Git repository without switching the branch of the rest of the repository? In Subversion, I could just use `svn switch` on any subfolder, and everything would Just Work™, but I haven't found an equivalent in Git.

Ideally, when I'm working in the folder that's common to the two branches, I'd like to be able to switch branches in that folder, make commits to either branch, and do all the other useful Git goodness, without having to wait for the other folder to be more-or-less completely rewritten.

Just to complicate matters, I'm using `git svn`; the two main branches I mention are the trunk and a branch in the underlying Subversion repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a new solution to this: [`git-new-workdir`](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/). It doesn't let me switch a subfolder, but it does let me have separate working directories which I can switch between instead of using a "switch" operation.

It solves the underlying problem: I can have one working directory for each of the main branches, swap between them whenever I want with no cost, and the two working directories share the same Git repository, so I don't need two separate clones as [Ben Lee](/users/480943/ben-lee) suggested in the [comments to his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7583006/220155).

To get at the script on my (Cygwin) system, I needed to download and install the Git source code; it's in the `contrib` directory there.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in git with something called "sparse checkout". First, you have to enable this on your project:

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
```

Then, you have to set up the directories you want to check out. Open `.git/info/sparse-checkout` in an editor, and list the directories you want to limit the checkout to (each on a separate line). Then run this command:

```
git read-tree -m -u HEAD
```

You can disable sparecheckout at some later point to return the behavior to normal.

Comment: Not quite perfect: This deleted the directories that weren't listed in the `sparse-checkout` file, whereas I'd have preferred them to hang around and just be left alone. Nonetheless, this looks to be a pretty good option, thank you!

Comment: In particular, the problem with this is that when I start and finish with the sparse mode, I need to checkout/delete all the other directories. So the swaps between branches are quick, thanks to the sparse checkout, but it's still slow to enter and leave that mode.

Comment: @me_and, yeah I agree that is an issue. Not sure the best way around it. Maybe store two clones of the repository on your computer? One copy set up with a sparsecheckout for the common dirs, and one copy with the regular full checkout?

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to be able to do that, the only way in Git would be to set up the subfolder as a submodule http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html

I guess the reason SVN allows this is because it places separate .svn files in each subfolder which keep track of the current state.

Comment: This looked promising, but I can't see it working with `git svn` without losing access (or at least making access much more complex) to all the tags and branches in the underlying Subversion repository.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. Git is a content tracker and tracks content changes, not files or folders.

As a workaround you could use git-svn to fetch your SVN trunk in one Git repository and the SVN branch in another.

Comment: Actually, Git explicitly tracks files and folders (or at least, files and file trees), *not* content changes. That's one of the fundamental back-end differences between how Git and Subversion store their repositories.